# Move a div with mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do exactly as it is in this link. 
(The stripe on the banners with the read more link)
https://toyota.jp/vitz

What I tried so far doesn't work as expected. It moves the whole stripe apart from the range.

```js
$(document).on("click mousemove", ".spec-slider-wrap", function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var newposX = x - 700;
  var newposY = y - 350;
  $(".stripe").css("transform", "translate3d(" + newposX + "px," + newposY + "px,0px)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="word">More</span>
  <span class="arrow-wrap">
    <span class="arrow-pulse-right"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `It moves the whole stripe` you have `$(".stripe")` in your handler; did you mean `$(this)`?

Comment: `.stripe` is not present in your html markup.

Comment: There is no `.spec-slider-wrap` element in your HTML. Please add an accurate snippet of the relevant code to the question

Answer (score 0):

here the working code.
https://jsbin.com/geyudivuru/edit?html,css,js,output

```
  <div class="parent" style="">
    <div class="stripe">
      <span class="word">More</span>
        <span class="arrow-wrap">
          <span class="arrow-pulse-right"></span>
        </span>
     <div>
  </div>
```

```
.stripe {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  display: none;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px; 
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```
$ = jQuery;
$(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var newposX = x - 700;
  var newposY = y;
  $('.stripe').css({top: newposY, display: 'block'})
});

$('.parent').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.stripe').css({top: 0, display: 'none'})
})
```

add styling to divs and you'll get what you need.

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. What exactly have you changed? The snippet I edited in to the question appears to do nothing.

Comment: see the updated answer above for working code. as for issues in your snippet:
1. you are missing the stripe element in your markup.
2. there is no .spec-slider-wrap element.
3. You were missing the end position for dive and mouse leave event.
also for simplisity i used position absolute which works fine. hope this answeres your question and helps on your task.